# To find the greatest value of a product whose sum is constant

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For a given sum of two numbers;

$$a+b=S$$
To maximize,$$P=ab$$ is attained when the two factors are the same (so we've been taught), i.e.,

$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2{\ge}ab$$
Also, generally, for $n$ numbers, 
$$\left(\frac{a+b+c+...n}{n}\right)^n {\ge} abc...n$$

Question:

$1.$ I understand the proof that if $a=b$, the product, $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$ is greater than or equal to $ab$, but how is it the greatest product?

$2.$ For the general case, I understand this is also the case for AM-GM inequality but I don't understand it is the maximum product when the sum is constant.

$3.$ How is it the idea of equality extended to maximising the the product $a^mb^nc^p...k^t$ with given sum $a+b+...+k=Z$

Generally, I don't understand how it is the maximum for both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2.

I think you mean that the variables are positives.

If $a+b+c+...=Z$ so by AM-GM $abc...\leq\left(\frac{Z}{n}\right)^n$.

The equality occurs for $a=b=c=...=\frac{Z}{n}$, which says which you wish.

3. By AM-GM we obtain:
   $$a^mb^nc^p...=m^m\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^mn^n\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^n...\leq$$
   $$\leq m^mn^n\left(\frac{m\cdot\frac{a}{m}+n\cdot\frac{b}{n}+...}{m+n+...}\right)^{m+n+...}= m^mn^n...\left(\frac{Z}{N}\right)^{N},$$
   where $N=m+n+...$.

Comment: Yes when the variables are positive, But how is this maximum?

Comment: @jyotishraj thoudam If $x\leq2$ so what is a maximal value of $x$?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I was blinded by something else. Now I finally see it

Comment: @jyotishraj thoudam Because the right side is constant!

Comment: Is this all a consequence of the AM-GM inequality. Or can we prove the other way round?

Comment: @jyotishraj thoudam By I think AM-GM is an easiest way here. For 1. we have also $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2-ab=\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}\geq0$.

Comment: I mean, can we prove the maximum product by the equality of the factor argument for the $n$ case and proving the am-gm inequality later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55584/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-jyotishraj-thoudam).

Comment: Yes, I get the idea that if $a=b$ then $ab$ is maximum. But I don't understand the fact for the $n$ number case. For only two, we can show it using the elementary $(a-b)^2$ argument

Comment: For example. If $a+b=5$ so by AM-GM $ab\leq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$. The equality occurs for $a=b=\frac{5}{2}$, which says that $\frac{25}{4}$ is a maximal value of $ab$ if $a+b=5$ and $a>0$, $b>0$.